# Should I improve my computer science knowledge by focusing on one skill at a time, or doing a little bit of everything more frequently?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, programming-languages

I'm currently learning things like algorithms, data structures, machine learning and some programming languages. Should i distribute my work or should i focalized for a certain period on one thing, and then switch to another?

Comment: This sounds pretty opinion-based and subjective to me, so not appropriate here.